# I have an array of object which needs to restructured into a desired format. I tried using array destructuring using iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

The desired output should be as follows. I tried object restructuring way but i could not push the out as an object. If you can just guide me what are the other array methods i can use to get the desired array

```js
const sample = [
  {
    name: 'Bike',
    series: [
      { date: '01-01-2020', value: '4$' },
      { date: '02-01-2020', value: '3$' },
      { date: '03-01-2020', value: '3.5$' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Watch',
    series: [
      { date: '01-01-2020', value: '1$' },
      { date: '02-01-2020', value: '2$' },
      { date: '03-01-2020', value: '5$' }
    ]
  }
]

const output = [
  { date: '01-01-2020', 'bike-value': '4$', 'watch-value': '1$' },
  { date: '02-01-2020', 'bike-value': '3$', 'watch-value': '2$' },
  { date: '03-01-2020', 'bike-value': '3.5$', 'watch-value': '5$'}
]
```

What i tried is as follows. But i cannot make this into a object to push into an empty array.

```
for (const {name: n, series: [{date: d , value: v}]} of sample) {
  console.log('name: ' + n + ', date: ' + d + ', value: ' + v);
}
```

Comment: can you show us what you've tried even if it didn't work

Comment: I just added my code

Comment: what about this date `'03-01-2020'`?

Comment: Sorry that too, I didn't  format it properly. Added it.

Answer (score 3):

You could loop through the `sample` array and then loop through the each `series` array. Create a `group` object which has each `date` as key and the object needed in the final output it's value. Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of the `group` object as an array

```js
const sample=[{name:"Bike",series:[{date:"01-01-2020",value:"4$"},{date:"02-01-2020",value:"3$"},{date:"03-01-2020",value:"3.5$"}]},{name:"Watch",series:[{date:"01-01-2020",value:"1$"},{date:"02-01-2020",value:"2$"},{date:"03-01-2020",value:"5$"}]}];
 
const group = {} 

for (const { name, series } of sample) {
  for (const { date, value } of series) {
    group[date] = group[date] || { date };
    group[date][`${name.toLowerCase()}-value`] = value
  }
}

const output = Object.values(group)

console.log(output)
```

The group object looks like this:

```
{
  "01-01-2020": {
    "date": "01-01-2020",
    "bike-value": "4$",
    "watch-value": "1$"
  },
  "02-01-2020": {
    "date": "02-01-2020",
    "bike-value": "3$",
    ...
   },
  "03-01-2020": {
     ....
  }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer. Can you explain me what happens inside the `series` loop? . Also can you tell me where did you assign `date` as a key in `group` object? Sorry, It looks simpler but somehow can't comprehend

Comment: @DeepikaDeepi The `group` object has each date as it's key. What `group[date] = group[date] || { date }` code does is: If the  `group[date]` exists for current `date` being looped, then use that. Else, assign a new object `{ date }` to it. { date } is using [Shorthand property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). It's similar to `{ "date": date }`. Then update the `group[date][<name>-value]` property to `value`

Answer (score 1):

A simple nested constructor should work here:

```
const sample =  [
                    {name : 'Bike', series : 
                        [{date : '01-01-2020', value : '4$'},
                        {date : '02-01-2020', value : '3$'},
                        {date : '03-01-2020', value : '3.5$'}]
                    },
                    {name : 'Watch', series : 
                        [{date : '01-01-2020', value : '1$'},
                         {date : '02-01-2020', value : '2$'},
                         {date : '03-01-2020', value : '5$'}]
                    }

      ];


let results = [];

for (let i = 0; i< sample[0].series.length; i++){
    //get date and 'Bike' value from first value
    let newEntry = {date : sample[0].series[i].date, bikeValue : sample[0].series[i].value};

    //find the corresponding 'Watch' value with another loop
    let watchValue = 0;

    for (let i2 = 0; i2<sample[1].series.length; i2++){
        if(sample[1].series[i2].date == newEntry.date){
            watchValue = sample[1].series[i2].value;
        }
    }

    newEntry.watchValue = watchValue;

    //push new object into results array
    results.push(newEntry);
}

console.log(results);
```